# How to split an array into chunks and find the sum of the chunks and store the output as an array in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
+-----+------------------------+
|Index|   finalArray           |
+-----+------------------------+
|1    |[0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7]|
|2    |[0, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5]|
+-----+------------------------+
```

I want to break the array into chunks of 2 and then find the sum of each chunks and store the resultant array in the column finalArray. It will look like below:

```
+-----+---------------------+
|Index|    finalArray       |
+-----+---------------------+
|1    |[2, 3, 5, 9]         |
|2    |[4, 7, 6, 7]         |
+-----+---------------------+
```

I am able to do it by creating an UDF but looking for an better and optimised way. Preferably if I can handle it using a withColumn and passing flagArray to do it without having to write an UDF.

```
@udf(ArrayType(DoubleType()))
def aggregate(finalArray,chunkSize):
   n = int(chunkSize)
   aggsum = []
   final = [finalArray[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(finalArray) + n - 1) // n )]
   for item in final:
      agg = 0
      for j in item:
         agg += j
         aggsum.append(agg)
   return aggsum
```

I am not able to use the below expression in UDF hence I used loops

```
[sum(finalArray[x:x+2]) for x in range(0, len(finalArray), chunkSize)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For spark 2.4+, you can try [sequence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#sequence) + [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#transform):

```
from pyspark.sql.function import expr

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  (1, [0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7]),
  (2, [0, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5])
], ["Index", "finalArray"])

df.withColumn("finalArray", expr("""
    transform(
      sequence(0,ceil(size(finalArray)/2)-1), 
      i -> finalArray[2*i] + ifnull(finalArray[2*i+1],0))
 """)).show(truncate=False)
+-----+------------+
|Index|finalArray  |
+-----+------------+
|1    |[2, 3, 5, 9]|
|2    |[4, 7, 6, 7]|
+-----+------------+
```

For a chunk-size of any N, use [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) function to do the sub-totals:

```
N = 3

sql_expr = """
    transform(
      /* create a sequence from 0 to number_of_chunks-1 */
      sequence(0,ceil(size(finalArray)/{0})-1),
      /* iterate the above sequence */
      i -> 
        /* create a sequence from 0 to chunk_size-1 
           calculate the sum of values containing every chunk_size items by their indices
         */
        aggregate(
          sequence(0,{0}-1),
          0L, 
          (acc, y) -> acc + ifnull(finalArray[i*{0}+y],0)
        )
    )
"""
df.withColumn("finalArray", expr(sql_expr.format(N))).show()                                                        
+-----+----------+
|Index|finalArray|
+-----+----------+
|    1| [2, 8, 9]|
|    2| [8, 9, 7]|
+-----+----------+
```

Comment: is there any way i can find Max value for each chunks using sequence + transform. I can do it using udf but since my dataframe contains around 12-18 million rows want to avoid udf as much as possible. Any help is appreciated

Comment: check: `sql_expr = "transform(sequence(0,ceil(size(finalArray)/{0})-1), i -> array_max(slice(finalArray,i*{0}+1,{0})))".format(N)`

Comment: it works like charm. thanks a lot for your promt and efficient response

Comment: done, didn't realize haven't done that already. Thanks a ton again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212127/discussion-between-saikat-and-jxc).

Comment: is there a way to make the solution provided by you to work if my array contains decimal values. In the above code 0L works with integers and 0D for doubles but I have array elements of decimal types of precision(38,15) and after doing the sum I would like the value to be in the same type and precision if possible.Also it would be great to have some documentation to have a better understanding

Comment: just change `0L` to `cast(0 as decimal(38,15))`

Comment: its throwing AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'aggregate(sequence(0, (2 - 1)), CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(38,15)), 

My expression is 
```
     transform_expr = """transform(sequence(0,ceil(size(finalArray)/{0})-1),i ->aggregate(sequence(0,{0}-1),cast(0 as decimal(38,15)),(acc, y) -> acc + ifnull(finalArray[i*{0}+y],0)))"""
```

Comment: you can try also force the datatype in the 3rd part of the aggregate function: `(acc, y) -> cast(acc + ifnull(finalArray[i*{0}+y],0) as decimal(38,15))`

Comment: thanks @jxc for your prompt response. Thanks a lot as always

Comment: @jxc i have try to connect with you , i have changed the spark version to 2.4 for the question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64660047/how-to-use-windowing-functions-efficiently-to-decide-next-n-number-of-rows-based , please undelete  your answer. now code is running.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different version of @jxc's solution using [`slice`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#slice) function with `transform` and `aggregate` functions.

The logic is for each element of the array we check if its index is a multiple of `chunk size` and use `slice` to get a subarray of `chunk size`. With `aggregate` we sum the elements of each sub-array. Finally using [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter) to remove nulls (corresponding to indexes that do not satisfy `i % chunk = 0`.

```
chunk = 2

transform_expr = f"""
filter(transform(finalArray, 
                 (x, i) -> IF (i % {chunk} = 0, 
                               aggregate(slice(finalArray, i+1, {chunk}), 0L, (acc, y) -> acc + y),
                               null
                              )
                ),
      x -> x is not null)
"""

df.withColumn("finalArray", expr(transform_expr)).show()

#+-----+------------+
#|Index|  finalArray|
#+-----+------------+
#|    1|[2, 3, 5, 9]|
#|    2|[4, 7, 6, 7]|
#+-----+------------+
```

Comment: is there a way to make the solution provided by you to work if my array contains decimal values. In the above code 0L works with integers and 0D for doubles but I have array elements of decimal types of precision(38,15) and after doing the sum I would like the value to be in the same type and precision if possible.Also it would be great to have some documentation to have a better understanding

Comment: @Saikat use `CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(38,15))` as the zero-value instead of `0L`. And make sure to change `acc + y` to `CAST(acc + y AS DECIMAL(38,15))` in the third argument of aggregate function, to avoid type mismatch errors.

Comment: thanks @blackbishop for your prompt response. Thanks a lot