# How to use windowing functions efficiently to decide next N number of rows based on N number of previous values

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, windowing

Hi i have the following data.

```
+----------+----+-------+-----------------------+
|      date|item|avg_val|conditions             |
+----------+----+-------+-----------------------+
|01-10-2020|   x|     10|                      0|
|02-10-2020|   x|     10|                      0|
|03-10-2020|   x|     15|                      1|
|04-10-2020|   x|     15|                      1|
|05-10-2020|   x|      5|                      0|
|06-10-2020|   x|     13|                      1|
|07-10-2020|   x|     10|                      1|
|08-10-2020|   x|     10|                      0|
|09-10-2020|   x|     15|                      1|
|01-10-2020|   y|     10|                      0|
|02-10-2020|   y|     18|                      0|
|03-10-2020|   y|      6|                      1|
|04-10-2020|   y|     10|                      0|
|05-10-2020|   y|     20|                      0|
+----------+----+-------+-----------------------+
```

I am tring to create a new column called flag level based on

1. if flag value is 0 then new column value will be 0.
2. if the flag is 1  then new column will be 1 and next four N  number of rows will be zero i.e no need to check next N value. this process will be applied for each item , that is partition by item will work.

I have used here N = 4,

I have used the below code but not effienntly windowing function is there any optimized way.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE t2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2
SELECT *,
MAX(conditions) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY item,`date` ROWS 4 PRECEDING ) AS new_row
FROM record
ORDER BY item,`date`;

 

 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE t3;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t3
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item,new_row ORDER BY item,`date`) AS e FROM t2;

 


SELECT *,CASE WHEN new_row=1 AND e%5>1 THEN 0 
WHEN new_row=1 AND e%5=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag FROM t3;
```

The output like as

```
+----------+----+-------+-----------------------+-----+
|      date|item|avg_val|conditions             |flag |
+----------+----+-------+-----------------------+-----+
|01-10-2020|   x|     10|                      0|    0|
|02-10-2020|   x|     10|                      0|    0|
|03-10-2020|   x|     15|                      1|    1|
|04-10-2020|   x|     15|                      1|    0|
|05-10-2020|   x|      5|                      0|    0|
|06-10-2020|   x|     13|                      1|    0|
|07-10-2020|   x|     10|                      1|    0|
|08-10-2020|   x|     10|                      0|    0|
|09-10-2020|   x|     15|                      1|    1|
|01-10-2020|   y|     10|                      0|    0|
|02-10-2020|   y|     18|                      0|    0|
|03-10-2020|   y|      6|                      1|    1|
|04-10-2020|   y|     10|                      0|    0|
|05-10-2020|   y|     20|                      0|    0|
+----------+----+-------+-----------------------+-----+
```

But i am unable to get the ouput , i have tried more.

Comment: that is not what window functions do. use a stored procedure with a cursor

Comment: @nbk , if i will use SP than query will be very slow because the number of records are too much(here i have taken an example) , i donot  want to do the same in looping.

Comment: a Table is noa arraym or list you have ine row, and there you can sse m,ax min what happen before or 3 line beforem, but you can check if n rows later is something happning,

Comment: The result obtaining process is iterative. So it cannot be obtained in single query. If your MySQL version is 8+ you may build stored procedure which does not use cursors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments(by @nbk and @Akina), you will need some sort of iterator to implement the logic. With SparkSQL and Spark version 2.4+, we can use the builtin function [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) and set an array of structs plus a counter as the accumulator. Below is an example dataframe and table named `record`(assume values in `conditions` column are either `0` or `1`):

```
val df = Seq(
    ("01-10-2020", "x", 10, 0), ("02-10-2020", "x", 10, 0), ("03-10-2020", "x", 15, 1),
    ("04-10-2020", "x", 15, 1), ("05-10-2020", "x", 5, 0), ("06-10-2020", "x", 13, 1),
    ("07-10-2020", "x", 10, 1), ("08-10-2020", "x", 10, 0), ("09-10-2020", "x", 15, 1),
    ("01-10-2020", "y", 10, 0), ("02-10-2020", "y", 18, 0), ("03-10-2020", "y", 6, 1),
    ("04-10-2020", "y", 10, 0), ("05-10-2020", "y", 20, 0)
).toDF("date", "item", "avg_val", "conditions")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("record")
```

### SQL:

```
spark.sql("""
  SELECT t1.item, m.*
  FROM (
    SELECT item,
      sort_array(collect_list(struct(date,avg_val,int(conditions) as conditions,conditions as flag))) as dta
    FROM record
    GROUP BY item
  ) as t1 LATERAL VIEW OUTER inline(
    aggregate(
      /* expr: set up array `dta` from the 2nd element to the last 
       *       notice that indices for slice function is 1-based, dta[i] is 0-based
       */
      slice(dta,2,size(dta)),
      /* start: set up and initialize `acc` to a struct containing two fields:
       * - dta: an array of structs with a single element dta[0]
       * - counter: number of rows after flag=1, can be from `0` to `N+1`
       */
      (array(dta[0]) as dta, dta[0].conditions as counter),
      /* merge: iterate through the `expr` using x and update two fields of `acc`
       * - dta: append values from x to acc.dta array using concat + array functions
       *        update flag using `IF(acc.counter IN (0,5) and x.conditions = 1, 1, 0)`
       * - counter: increment by 1 if acc.counter is between 1 and 4
       *            , otherwise set value to x.conditions
       */
      (acc, x) -> named_struct(
          'dta', concat(acc.dta, array(named_struct(
              'date', x.date,
              'avg_val', x.avg_val,
              'conditions', x.conditions,
              'flag', IF(acc.counter IN (0,5) and x.conditions = 1, 1, 0)
            ))),
          'counter', IF(acc.counter > 0 and acc.counter < 5, acc.counter+1, x.conditions)
        ),
      /* finish: retrieve acc.dta only and discard acc.counter */
      acc -> acc.dta
    )
  ) m
""").show(50)
```

### Result:

```
+----+----------+-------+----------+----+
|item|      date|avg_val|conditions|flag|
+----+----------+-------+----------+----+
|   x|01-10-2020|     10|         0|   0|
|   x|02-10-2020|     10|         0|   0|
|   x|03-10-2020|     15|         1|   1|
|   x|04-10-2020|     15|         1|   0|
|   x|05-10-2020|      5|         0|   0|
|   x|06-10-2020|     13|         1|   0|
|   x|07-10-2020|     10|         1|   0|
|   x|08-10-2020|     10|         0|   0|
|   x|09-10-2020|     15|         1|   1|
|   y|01-10-2020|     10|         0|   0|
|   y|02-10-2020|     18|         0|   0|
|   y|03-10-2020|      6|         1|   1|
|   y|04-10-2020|     10|         0|   0|
|   y|05-10-2020|     20|         0|   0|
+----+----------+-------+----------+----+
```

**Where:**

1. use `groupby` to collect rows for the same item into an array of structs named **dta** column with 4 fields: *date*, *avg_val*, *conditions* and *flag* and sorted by *date*
2. use `aggregate` function to iterate through the above array of structs, update the **flag** field based on **counter** and **conditions** (details see the above SQL code comments)
3. use `Lateral VIEW` and [inline](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#inline) function to explode the resulting array of structs from the aggregate function

**Notes:**

(1) the proposed SQL is for N=4, where we have `acc.counter IN (0,5)` and `acc.counter < 5` in the SQL. For any N, adjust the above to: `acc.counter IN (0,N+1)` and `acc.counter < N+1`, the below shows the result for `N=2` with the same sample data:

```
+----+----------+-------+----------+----+
|item|      date|avg_val|conditions|flag|
+----+----------+-------+----------+----+
|   x|01-10-2020|     10|         0|   0|
|   x|02-10-2020|     10|         0|   0|
|   x|03-10-2020|     15|         1|   1|
|   x|04-10-2020|     15|         1|   0|
|   x|05-10-2020|      5|         0|   0|
|   x|06-10-2020|     13|         1|   1|
|   x|07-10-2020|     10|         1|   0|
|   x|08-10-2020|     10|         0|   0|
|   x|09-10-2020|     15|         1|   1|
|   y|01-10-2020|     10|         0|   0|
|   y|02-10-2020|     18|         0|   0|
|   y|03-10-2020|      6|         1|   1|
|   y|04-10-2020|     10|         0|   0|
|   y|05-10-2020|     20|         0|   0|
+----+----------+-------+----------+----+
```

(2) we use `dta[0]` to initialize `acc` which includes both the values and  datatypes of its fields. Ideally, we should make sure data types of these fields right so that all calculations are correctly conducted. for example when calculating `acc.counter`, if `conditions` is StringType, `acc.counter+1` will return a StringType with a DoubleType value

```
spark.sql("select '2'+1").show()
+---------------------------------------+
|(CAST(2 AS DOUBLE) + CAST(1 AS DOUBLE))|
+---------------------------------------+
|                                    3.0|
+---------------------------------------+
```

Which could yield floating-point errors when comparing their value with integers using `acc.counter IN (0,5)` or `acc.counter < 5`. Based on OP's feedback, this produced incorrect result without any WARNING/ERROR message.

- One workaround is to specify exact field types using CAST when setting up the 2nd argument of aggregate function so it reports ERROR when any types mismatch, see below:

  ```
  CAST((array(dta[0]), dta[0].conditions) as struct<dta:array<struct<date:string,avg_val:string,conditions:int,flag:int>>,counter:int>),
  ```
- Another solution it to force types when creating `dta` column, in this example, see `int(conditions) as conditions` in below code:

  ```
  SELECT item,
    sort_array(collect_list(struct(date,avg_val,int(conditions) as conditions,conditions as flag))) as dta
  FROM record
  GROUP BY item
  ```
- we can also force datatype inside the calculating, for example, see `int(acc.counter+1)` below:

  ```
  IF(acc.counter > 0 and acc.counter < 5, int(acc.counter+1), x.conditions)
  ```

Comment: I am getting this error in scala version 2.11.8 and its working fine in scala version 2.12.8  --- -- -- --- -- Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'FROM' expecting {<EOF>, 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 3, pos 2)

Comment: can we run this code in scala 2.11.8 as its returning mismatched input 'FROM' at line (line 3, pos 2)

Comment: mismatched input '(' expecting {')' for sort_array(collect_list(struct(date

Comment: check if it is working now, tested on Spark 2.4.4 + Scala 2.11.12

Comment: same error : Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:  mismatched input '(' expecting {')'  == SQL ==
SELECT item,sort_array(collect_list(date,avg_val,conditions,conditions as flag)) as dta FROM record
-----------------------------------^^^

Comment: did you copy/paste my SQL code? or can you run it on spark-shell? I am not able to replicate the ERROR you mentioned.or what is the exact version of Spark?

Comment: <java.version>1.8</java.version>
<spark.version>2.1.0</spark.version>
<scala.version>2.11</scala.version>

Comment: OK, this only works on Spark 2.4.0+, you mentioned you have spark 2.4+, aren't you?

Comment: Oh! My bad luck, i am using a library in this project that require above comment configuaraton so i have to change my library version.will this code will not works for 2.1 version?

Comment: the proposed answer is only valid for Spark 2.4+. it's important to list the Spark version accurately since there are significant improvement over version 2.0 -> 2.3 -> 2.4 -> 3.0 which could lead to completely difference approaches. For spark 2.1.0 which does not support aggregate function, you might have to go with UDF for this task.